# Single JavaScript command (jeditable) for much value unique ID

Tags: javascript, jeditable

I have a javascript program (for jeditable):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#123').Editable ({
showbuttons: true
});
});
</ script>
```

The problem: ID variable has many values each unique (example: id='123', id='222', id='232', id='242', id='142', etc ...). How can I write GET element ID and just a single javascript command, (so do not write javascript commands above one by one). Please suggestions and thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Assign each of those elements a CSS class. Then you can do:

```
$(function () {
    $('.someclass').Editable ({
        showbuttons: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write in CSS
and how to get the value of each ID?
thanks for the response

Comment: You're asking very basic questions. It's probably best to read up on some tutorials about CSS. For the elements, all you have to do is add a class and it doesn't need any styling. For example `<div id="#123" class="someclass">...</div>`. What do you mean by "get the value of each ID"?

Comment: I generate ID using the command: uniqid(), and I dont know how to get the id value of each (using getElementById does not work), thank you...

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion above and made ​​it perfect,,,! it's work .... Thank you very much!!